# How to convert number to argb value?

Tags: java, c#, rgb

How can you convert a number into an `argb` value such that

```
0 -> 0,0,0,0
1 -> 0,0,0,1
...
(16^8)-1 -> 255,255,255,255
```

and vice versa so

```
0,0,0,0 -> 0
0,0,0,1 -> 1
...
255,255,255,255 -> (16^8)-1
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you show me what you've attempted?

Comment: Some clarification why existing methods like [Color.FromArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx) are not working would be useful... Along with sample code that you can't get working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely ignoring system methods, you can implement a custom method to do what you ask in C# like the following:

```
public static long argbToLong(int a, int r, int g, int b)
{
    new[] { a, r, g, b }.Select((v, i) => new { Name = "argb"[i].ToString(), Value = v }).ToList()
        .ForEach(arg =>
        {
            if (arg.Value > 255 || arg.Value < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(arg.Name, arg.Name + " must be between or equal to 0-255");
        });
    long al = (a << 24) & 0xFF000000;
    long rl = (r << 16) & 0x00FF0000;
    long gl = (g << 8) & 0x0000FF00;
    long bl = b & 0x000000FF;
    return al | rl | gl | bl;
}

public static Tuple<int, int, int, int> longToArgb(long argb)
{
    var max = Math.Pow(16, 8) - 1;
    if (argb < 0 || argb > max)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("argb", "argb must be between or equal to 0-" + max);
    int a = (int)((argb & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
    int r = (int)((argb & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
    int g = (int)((argb & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
    int b = (int)(argb & 0x000000FF);
    return new Tuple<int, int, int, int>(a, r, g, b);
}
```

Wasn't sure what language, since C# and Java is tagged.

Answer (score 2):

As additional solution to the answer above,  given the sample code below, the result of `(16^8)-1` is `23`. Which you would like to be of color white. Is there any special reason to do this? Refering to [Color](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs,1f25b4614bb23053)

This is what you want to do:

```
int argb = (16 ^ 8) - 1; //Result is 23 any reason for this?
```

If we use the same color conversion of `Color` object.

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
c.ToArgb(); //We get -1
```

Which we will get on the same result with this solution:

```
int v = (c.A << 24) + (c.R << 16) + (c.G << 8) + c.B; //Result is -1
```

Revert it back:

```
int a = (v >> 24) & 0xFF;
int r = (v >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (v >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (v) & 0xFF;
```

Try to check the above reference (and experiment) if this will fit your need.

Comment: The reason `(16 ^ 8) - 1` is 23 is because `^` is the C# bitwise OR operator. Not "to the power of" as the OP was suggesting (psuedo code). The correct code would be `Math.Pow(16,8) - 1`. Your methods (and the system ones) will not give the desired result of the OP, since they use only use 32 bit integers. See my answer.

Comment: @caesay thanks for the clarification. I thought it was the `bitwise ^`.

Comment: this still doesn't change the fact that your answer (and the .Net framework) is using 32bit unchecked integers, which result in negative numbers for a lot of argb values, and the OP specified this was not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitwise operators with 8 bits offset. For example, in RGB `255,255,128` to integer would be `(255 << 16) + (255 << 8) + (128)`

If you need another octet just add it with << 24.. Like `(a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b` ..